# MySQL UPDATE return value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I started coding a simple script that reads IDs from CSV and then sets the same email address (in DB) for ALL users from CSV. Simple enough...(using PDO)
reading of data from CSV is ok. It's the update part that is giving me headaches.

```
 $sSQL = "UPDATE users SET email = 'something@something.com' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '%s'";
 foreach ($aUsers as $sCustomerId) {
    $sQuery = sprintf($sSQL, $sCustomerId);

    if (!$db->exec($sQuery)) {
        printf("There was an error updating user %s in database.<br>", $sCustomerId);
        $aFailed[] = $sCustomerId;
    } else {
        printf("User %s successfully updated.<br>", $sCustomerId);
        $success++;
    }
}
```

script is really easy. The problem is that mysql doesn't UPDATE the user in DB if he already has that email address so it will return 0 (0 rows affected which is ok). Which is also the same thing mysql returns if error occures during update. And that is what's driving me nuts. How do I distinguish between "no rows affected" and "error occured". I tried using different PDO::ATTR_ERRMODEs and was expecting that at least in the case of error it will throw an exception (which kind of PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION should do) which I can than catch but it doesn't. Then I trid to use

```
if ($db->exec($sQuery) === FALSE)
```

also doesn't work. The script now works but the problem is that I can't distinguish "error" from "no affected rows".

Is that behavior in mysql new or? Because I can't remember having that problem in the past when writing such simple scripts for update...

Manual says: "If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it."

Comment: Have you tried PDOStatement::rowCount already? It returns the affected rows by the query. so check if its 0 or more :)

Comment: You should check for "$db->errorCode()" after update to see if an error occured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably could use `errorCode()` AND `errorInfo()` to identify an error.

`errorCode()` function returns NULL, if query has no problems.

Example:

```
$db->exec($sQuery);
if ($db->errorCode() !== NULL) {
    // Additional error info from: $db->errorInfo()
    printf("There was an error updating user %s in database.<br>", $sCustomerId);
    $aFailed[] = $sCustomerId;
} else {
    printf("User %s successfully updated.<br>", $sCustomerId);
    $success++;
}
```

PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO, try to do `prepare` and then `execute`, which returns `true` on success, `false` on error

```
$sSQL = "UPDATE users SET email = 'something@something.com' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :customer_id";
$sth = $db->prepare($sSQL);
if(!$sth->execute(array(':customer_id' => $sCustomerId)))
{
    printf("There was an error updating user %s in database.<br>", $sCustomerId);
} else {
    printf("User %s successfully updated.<br>", $sCustomerId);   
}
```

It's a good pratice for keeping your script secure. Execute will bind params, so there is no need to escape or quote them.